# is it posible change the namespace of a dll?

Tags: c#, dll

well i am working for PocketPc and it has a library (`System.data`) and
(`System.data.sqlclient`) then THEY are not complete libraries then i need use 
`System.data` (the complete library) but now i have 2 dll's calls (`System.data`)
and the complete library has `System.data.sqlclient` too, then i have problem with them, so
if i only use the complete library i have another problem, cuz the `System.data`( no complete library) has one thing wich `System.data`(Complete library) doesn't have, so i need use 2 dlls (with same namespace) and i have problems...

Comment: Please clean up your post with better grammar, it is hard to understand your question and it could be closed. If it does get closed you can still edit your question and it can be reopened.

Comment: Is the "incomplete" `System.Data` a subset of the "complete" `System.Data`?  What happens if you just use the "complete" one?  It sounds like you're running into an issue between the full .NET Framework and the Client Profile .NET Framework.  Something is using the Client Profile, but something else needs the full.  If that's the case, installing the full Framework should work fine.  You definitely don't want to pick and choose DLL's between the two.

Comment: the .dll names doesn't matter, you could have different namespaces in the same .dll files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in MSDN and [a tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) to use them in visual studio.

From the command line compiler the references are declared as :

```
/r:SystDataOfficial=System.Data.dll
/r:SystDataOther=data.dll
```

Then in your code :

```
extern alias SystDataOfficial;
extern alias SystDataOther;

var c = new SystDataOfficial::System.Data.SqlClient();
```

You could also put only one of the dlls as an alias and use the other one normally

Please note that the types won't be usable together. This code won't work :

```
// Expect SystDataOfficial::SomeConstant
SystDataOfficial::System.Data.SqlClient.SomeMethod(SystDataOther::SomeConstant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see

[extern alias (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) on MSDN

But they still will be different types, and you won't be able to pass objects created by one to methods in the other.